# npm nlf - extracting version numbers out afterwards (using RegEx)

Tags: regex, npm, atom-editor

I been trying to use the awesome package `nlf` to create a list of licenses

but would like to remove the specific version number from the massive list it generated

I'm just learning RegEx and got this expression so far

```
\b[^\w]@*[\d.]\b
```

[image]

But it seems to grab into license version number as well..

I just want to take out the number in between the `@` and space.

Here is some example text

```
jsesc@1.3.0 [license(s): MIT]
package.json:  MIT

json-schema@0.2.3 [license(s): AFLv2.1, AFLv2.1/BSD, BSD]
package.json:  AFLv2.1, AFLv2.1/BSD, BSD
readme files: BSD

json-schema-traverse@0.3.1 [license(s): MIT]
package.json:  MIT
license files: MIT

json-stable-stringify@1.0.1 [license(s): MIT]
package.json:  MIT
license files: MIT
readme files: MIT

json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 [license(s): ISC]
package.json:  ISC
license files: ISC

json5@0.4.0 [license(s): MIT]
package.json:  MIT
readme files: MIT

json5@0.5.1 [license(s): MIT]
package.json:  MIT
license files: MIT
```

FYI: I'm using Atom if it matters..

Comment: Try `\b@[\d.]*\d`

Comment: No results in Atom

Comment: Well, it seems to work in all regex101 engines - https://regex101.com/r/nGNhUq/1

Comment: OMG! I had a blank space (first character) in my search field! No wonder I couldn't make it work.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work as expected because the `@` is matched with `\b[^\w]` (any non-word char preceded with a word char) and `@*` pattern does not match any., and `[\d.]\b` matches an

You may use

```
\b@[\d.]*\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGNhUq/1).

**Details**

- `\b@` - a `@` that is preceded with any word char (letter, digit or `_`)
- `[\d.]*` - 0+ digits or `.`, as many as possible
- `\d` - a digit.